# Why is an AES encrypted string saving as blank to MySQL table with Ruby?

Tags: mysql, ruby, aes, 8-bit

I have a model called Encryption which generates an AES encrypted string and saves that to a database table called encryptions. My encryption table schema is as follows:

```
id : bigint unsigned
user_id : bigint unsigned
encryption : VARCHAR(128) (utf8_unicode_ci)
created_at : datetime
updated_at : datetime
```

However, when I call .save on my encryption model instance, the value for encryption.encryption (in the database) is blank ('').

Here's the contents of the model:

```
ruby-1.9.2-head :005 > encryption
 => #<Encryption id: nil, user_id: 1, encryption: "\xD6\xD6\x95\x15\x0F\x92\xC6\x01\x86\x1E\x88\xD1\xB0\x1D\xE0\xEC", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

As you can see, it does have a value in the model. Any ideas on why the field is saving as blank in the database?

Comment: It doesn't look blank to me... "\xD6\xD6\x95\x15\x0F\x92\xC6\x01\x86\x1E\x88\xD1\xB0\x1D\xE0\xEC"

Comment: Not in the model. But in the database, it's blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the strongbox gem to do something similar, and it requested a column type of `:binary`, not text, maybe you could try that...

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be saving a string into a bigint column, which won't work. Switch it to a text column type.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been VARCHAR(128). I've corrected this in the post.